# 2 localizations inside a WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development, localization

I'm building a theme which includes a separate "section" and I want to make both the theme and the separate section localizable. However, I don't want to have them under the same textdomain.

Would someone advise against doing this? Could there be any issues?

I don't want to have the separate section as a plugin.

This is what could appear inside e.g. `functions.php`:

```
__('String', 'themename');
__('Another string', 'somethingelse');
```

Comment: hmm... have you tried that? does it work? what have you done to call multilple translation files meaning with this line (for example): load_theme_textdomain('sagive', $lang);

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is *possible*. You can load as many language files as you want:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'text_domain_1', get_template_directory() . '/languages/td1' ) );
load_theme_textdomain( 'text_domain_2', get_template_directory() . '/languages/td2' ) );
```

In terms of performance it may be *useful* if want to [separate front-end and back-end translations](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55190/73).

But it is the *wrong solution* if do this to manage plugin code that you have moved into a theme. For example the notorious contact form, shortcodes or a dashboard widget – these parts should be handled by real plugins.

TL;DR: It depends on the problem you want to solve.