# Translate a string to a language with masculin/feminine nouns

Tags: localization

So in english we don't have gendered nouns.  It is always "a table" or "a desk" with no need to worry about it being "une table" or "un tableau" (french).  So my question is that when working on the french .mo file, how does one translate a string such as :

You can include a %s in a childtheme

since the "a" depends on what the %s is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a problem if every string gets its own template for translation.

If you use the string `You can include a %s in a childtheme.` more than one time for different nouns it is not translatable.

An example, taken from a [recent article](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/05/register-custom-post-type.html#comment-9983): `New %s` is in German (yes, we have gendered nouns too) …

- Neues Buch (for a book, neutral)
- Neuer Film (for a movie, masculine)

… so you have to write `New book` *and* `New movie` or `You can include a logo in a child theme.` *and* `You can include a stylesheet in a child theme.`.

*Side note*

That’s one of the reasons why translation files take so much memory: You have to “repeat” many very similar strings. While a WordPress installation in English will probably run fine with 32MB PHP memory it will just die if you use the same with a German or French translation.

If your theme or plugin is using many translatable strings for front-end and back-end consider using *two* files: one for the back-end and a separate file for the front-end.

```
load_theme_textdomain( 
    'your_text_domain', 
    get_template_directory() . '/languages' . ( is_admin() ? '/backend' : '/frontend' )
);
```

The WordPress core just changed to this system for better performance.

Comment: thanks toscho. i guess i need to dig deeper into the purpose of the original string and see what %s is being used for.  how do i separate the back-end and front-end strings?

Comment: @helgatheviking see my update.

Comment: gotcha.  thanks for that. one more thing, if the string is only used once, can you leave it with %s and just provide clarification of context?

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes, you do that. But I don’t see how this would make translation easier. The context parameter has to be a hard coded string too; you cannot use a PHP variable here.

Comment: "*yes, we have gendered nouns too*" remembers me of Mark Twain: *Whenever the literary German dives into a sentence, that is the last you are going to see of him till he emerges on the other side of his Atlantic with a verb in his mouth.*

Comment: ok, so then the best thing to do is keep the string in tact.  "You can use a book in your child theme" (obviously not really a book)

Comment: @toscho so it is recommended to split the mo and po files into admin and frontend?

Comment: @helgatheviking Depends on the size. I wouldn’t care about a memory increase of 1—2MB. Test it with a _real_ translation, watch the used memory with Xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Helga, you Viking... I'd say this is one dam of a simple and intriguing question..!

In a simple view, looks like the issue is the `%s` and not the gender:

> You can include `%s` in a child theme

Complexifying the matter, I donnow if a [gettext toscho's retranslate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615) wizardry would address this, or if it is off-topic and should be taken care of by [WP Polyglots](http://wppolyglots.wordpress.com/).

<sup>side note: [How-to: Translate plural forms for themes/plugins with PoEdit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/33312/12615)</sup>

Comment: phew, this translation stuff is complicated. clearly i take being a native-anglophone for granted!  if this thread would be better at WP Polyglots I hope someone will move it.

Comment: Well, now, *au contraire*, with **the canonical answer** provided by toscho, WP Polyglots may use this post as reference for the subject :)